# fasterxml Jackson - Allow null values in json when deserializing

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, dropwizard

Say, we have this code snippet:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class ClassName implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2639184385302562144L;
    String xyz;
}
```

If I try to map a json `{"xyz": null}` to this object (using dropwizard, accepting this model in api call), I get this exception:

```
! java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: _nullProvider
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.OptimizedSettableBeanProperty._deserializeString(OptimizedSettableBeanProperty.java:161) ~[jackson-module-afterburner-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SettableStringMethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableStringMethodProperty.java:54) ~[jackson-module-afterburner-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:222) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:218) ~[jackson-module-afterburner-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:122) ~[jackson-module-afterburner-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
```

The aim is to ignore keys with `null` values, both when encoding to json and when decoding from json. In such a case, if I deserialize `{"xyz": null}`, the final object should have the xyz as `NULL`. If a serialize the resulting json should be `{}`.

Tried `@Nullable`, `@Optional`, didn't help. Presence or absence of `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` is not helping either.

dropwizard version = 0.9.2

Comment: Have you tried a `@ApiParam(value = "the string", required = false)` decorator ?

Comment: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1294 talks about this issue